# make div select unselect in reactjs using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i make div select and unselect like checkbox when adding and removing items from array. My add/remove functionality is working fine but i don't know how to control the view. I make a div that look a like checkbox.

Filter code :-

```
import React, { useContext, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useOnClickOutside from "hooks/outsideClick";
import DataProvider from "context/DataContext";

import filterData from "config/constants";

export default function FilterDropdown() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const {
    filter,
    setFilter,
    dataArray,
    setDataArray,
    checkArray,
    setCheckedArray,   
  } = useContext(DataProvider);
  const showFilter = () => setFilter(!filter);

  const handleFilterValues = (meta_name, meta_value) => {
    const index = dataArray.findIndex(({ value }) => value === meta_value);
    const data = [...dataArray];

    if (index > -1) {
      data.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      const entry = { name: meta_name, value: meta_value };
      data.push(entry);
    }
    setDataArray(data);
  };

  console.log(dataArray);

  return (
    <div className="hs-unfold ml-3">
      <div
        id="usersFilterDropdown"
        style={{
          minWidth: "20rem",
        }}
        className={`dropdown-unfold dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-right dropdown-card card-dropdown-filter-centered ${
          filter ? "hs-unfold-content-active" : "hs-unfold-content"
        }`}
        ref={ref}
      >
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body-filter">           
            <div className="filter-tabs">
              <ul className="screen-options-list">
                {filterData.map((filter, index) => {
                  return (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                      <li className="list-option">
                        <small className="nav-subtitle d-block">
                          {filter.value}
                        </small>
                      </li>
                      {filter.data
                        .filter((val) => {
                          if (search == "") {
                            return val;
                          } else if (
                            val.value
                              .toLowerCase()
                              .includes(search.toLowerCase())
                          ) {
                            return val;
                          }
                        })
                        .map((f, i) => {
                          return (
                            <div
                              className="filter-dropdown-side"
                              key={i}
                              onClick={() =>
                                handleFilterValues(filter.key, f.key)
                              }
                            >
                              <div
                                className="filter-check"
                              ></div>

                              <li className="filter-value">{f.value}</li>
                            </div>
                          );
                        })}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to trigger/control `filter-check` class using state variable or that i can use it somewhere else also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already storing the selected filter keys in `dataArray` you can use the below logic to determine whether or not to show or hide the check div.

```
<div className="filter-check"
     style={{
         display: dataArray.findIndex(({ value }) => value === f.key) > -1 
             ? 'block'
             : 'none'
     }}
></div>
```

This way you're using something that is already in stored in state (and will update as such) so you don't need to make a new state value to keep track of what filter options have been selected.

Comment: but i want to remove the uncheck from another component also..

Comment: @Gurupalsingh you mean you want to make the element `filter-check` a shared component to be used by separate components that have their own filter state values?

Comment: No, i want to add a state that trigger true and false on adding and removing items. As i want to use that state somewhere else also .. for example if you add some filter and show tags which are having that cross button on it.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .25em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:focus::after {
  content: ' is selected'
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1">first</div>
<div tabindex="2">second</div>
<div tabindex="2">third</div>
```

Comment: i want to handle this from state